# Global Entry: Can non-residents use Enrollment on Arrival?

Tags: usa, uk-citizens, global-entry, cbp

I’m a UK-resident UK citizen, I’ve just been conditionally approved for Global Entry and I have a trip to New York in a couple of weeks.

There are no appointments available nearby while I’m there, but there’s an Enrollment on Arrival lane at the terminal I’ll be landing at.

My concern is the wording of the Enrollment on Arrival site:

> To complete the interview via EoA, you must be in possession of the following documents:
>
> - A valid passport. If you travel using more than one passport, please bring them all to the interview so that the information can be added to your file. This provides you with the ability to use multiple passports at the Global Entry kiosk.
> - **Documents providing evidence of residency. Examples are: driver's license (if the address is current), mortgage statement, rental payment statement, utility bill, etc. This is not required for minors.**
> - A permanent resident card (if applicable).

https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-arrival

Emphasis added - the implication seems to be that it’s only open to (US) residents. Or does this just mean I should bring proof of my UK address?

Have any non-residents successfully navigated EoA? What did they ask for?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it's only open to US residents? They want to confirm the address you gave them, it doesn't have to be in the US

Comment: “Evidence of residency” to me implies particular (US) residency, in the same sense as “permanent resident card”. If they wanted confirmation of my UK address I’d expect them to say “Proof of address”. Maybe that’s just a BE/AE language thing and I’m overthinking it!

Comment: @RobHogan it's definitely a BE/AE thing.

Comment: @littleadv thanks - if you want to post that as an answer I’d be happy to accept, and I’ll try to remember to follow up in a couple of weeks.. 

Comment: @RobHogan as a native speaker of US English I would say it is not at all a BE/AE thing.  I would read it just as you did.  It is further confusing because some people seem to use "residency" to denote legal status and "residence" to denote the place where someone lives, while others use the words interchangeably.

Comment: @phoog - Appreciate that, it certainly still reads to me that “evidence of residency” shouldn’t be something a “non-resident” can provide, but I don’t have much to lose by trying. The other factor is I can’t think why CBP should care where in the UK I live, given it’s not relevant to eligibility and I’ve already been through pre-vetting by UK Home Office to get this far. But US customs do ask a lot of questions, so maybe I shouldn’t be surprised!

Comment: @RobHogan while I think that the phrase is poorly chosen, I also think it means "proof of address." It may have been chosen to exclude the possibility that people might give proof of an address where they don't reside (such as a second home) or indeed of an address in the US if they don't reside there (the US asks visitors for a US address, so such confusion would be understandable). As to your address in the UK, it's probably part of the background check.  Having a home outside the US is also a little known requirement to enter the US as a tourist, though I'm not sure if that's relevant here.

Comment: That makes sense, although surely the UK phase of the background check is better placed to evaluate my proof of address - remains to be seen what a CBP officer will make of a UK council tax bill!

> Having a home outside the US is also a little known requirement to enter the US as a tourist, though I'm not sure if that's relevant here

Interesting, nonetheless! I didn’t know that.

Comment: I’m in the same situation, were you able to do enrollment on arrival as a UK resident, UK citizen for Global Entry? Thanks!

Comment: @BrianDoe unfortunately due to a delayed flight I arrived at JFK just as the EoA desk was closing, and they wouldn’t talk to me, so it’ll have to wait until my next trip. I think it would’ve been fine though, believe the answer here is correct. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documents they ask for are to prove your address. This has nothing to do with the residency in the immigration sense of it, they want to know where you actually live.

Comment: Thanks - I hope you’re right, will give it a try and update here.